# Is SonataUserBundle compatible with Symfony 3.3.*?

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Symfony 3.3, i am not sure Sonata User Bundle compatible with symfony 3.3 or not please let me know any one.

I saw people discussing an issue around compatibility with Symfony 3.3, but I don't recall seeing a clear response. Is there any updates?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I am using php 5.6 and symfony 3.3 after installing sonata user bundle i am getting these errors:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.6.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.21) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.5.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.21) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.4.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.21) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.15
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.15
```

my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
```

I con't move php 7.1 or symfony 2.8. Is there any way to do with php 5.6 and symfony3.3 in sonata user bundle

Comment: Please, if you need to reply, use comment under my question and not do no edit my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @DonCallisto can you let me know i edit my post

Comment: If you can't upgrade php, you can't use sf3.3 and sonata with that version. It's no possibile. Moreover [php 5.6 is out of active support and in one year will end its life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: ok ok Thank you so much @DonCallisto is there any issues with  php 7

Comment: @DonCallisto now i decide to  upgrade php 7, sonata compatible with symfony 3.3  and php7 ? right

Comment: if you upgrade, you should upgrade sonata aswell: `"sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.3",` should be `"sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.0". However be careful and read what you need to do in order to upgrade from `3` to `4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look to [`composer.json` file in `SonataUserBundle`](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/4.x/composer.json#L28-L33)

As you can see in link provided, these are the requirements

```
"symfony/console": "^2.8 || ^3.2 || ^4.0",
"symfony/form": "^2.8 || ^3.2 || ^4.0",
"symfony/http-foundation": "^2.8 || ^3.2 || ^4.0",
"symfony/security-acl": "^2.8 || ^3.0",
"symfony/security-core": "^2.8 || ^3.2 || ^4.0",
"symfony/translation": "^2.8 || ^3.2 || ^4.0"
```

So branch `4.x` is fine for symfony 3.3 [whereas branch `3.x` isn't](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/3.x/composer.json#L28-L32)

In order to use `SonataUserBundle` with sf3.3 you should update to `4.x` of this bundle (if you're not already using it)

Answer (score 0):

"config": {"bin-dir": "bin","platform": {"php": "7.1.3"}
   },

You just need to change this thing in composer.json file